# NetBeans non fast-forward update

Tags: push, netbeans-7, pull

I am using NetBeans 7.2.1 and am having trouble pushing a file after it has been committed.

The file is called 'test.php' and is a new file that has not been pushed to the server yet. The file has no PHP errors and the commit works successfully.

However, when I try and 'push' the file, the following error message pops up:

Push would result in a non fast-forward update.

If I do a 'pull', the pull completes successfully. If, after I have done the successful pull, I try and do a 'push', the same 'non fast-forward update' error pops up.

Answer (score 4):

I'm facing the same problem.
Please try pull and then merge.

Comment: Yes, please try the original git command instead of the built-in command in Netbeans.

Comment: ahh ... then: you might consider adding that clarification to your answer :-)

Comment: Actually, the steps are due to your situations. Basically, you can run $ git status and then follow the instructions git tells you. Maybe you need to merge or pull. After everything is okay, you can commit and push;

Answer (score 1):

Do a pull then merge the branches so it can track updates. Had the same problem you had on 7.4 and this fixed it.